# How to connect sparlyr in to a spark standalone cluster

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

This is how I am trying to connect to my cluster

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.1/")
config <- spark_config()
sc <- spark_connect(master = "spark://192.168.0.100:7077", config = 
config, version = '2.3.1')
```

This is the results:

```
Error in force(code) : 
  Failed while connecting to sparklyr to port (8880) for sessionid (88284): Gateway in port (8880) did not respond.
Path: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.1/bin/spark-submit
Parameters: --class, sparklyr.Shell, '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/sparklyr/java/sparklyr-2.3-2.11.jar', 8880, 88284
Log: /var/folders/dw/mx796jyn2ydgw0fj536q21tm0000gn/T//RtmpeStX3x/file27531f8f123_spark.log
---- Output Log ----


---- Error Log ----
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at several solutions, it was an easy way. The thing is that I am using spark on a Mac that was installed by Brew, so the path is one folder further in libexec insted of just 2.3.1 - Therefore now it works just fine.

```
sc <- spark_connect(master="spark://192.168.0.100:7077", 
                    version = "2.3.1",
                    config = conf,
                    spark_home = "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.1/libexec/
```